# Which is the best place to do intermediate Data Processing before building Power BI Visualisation?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, olap

This is a newbie question. Currently, I connect to an SSAS service from Excel and bring back data from multi-dimensional cubes. Some calculations (using cube data and one or two numbers are hardcoded in the excel) and what-if-analysis are performed and the data is filtered for a specific week of the calendar year (Week 2 - Jan 3, 2022 - Jan 9, 2022) and moved to another tab and that forms the basis of the Power BI report along with the original cube data.

Since this is a weekly report and someone has to open the excel, refresh data from the cube, perform what-if-analysis using goal seeker and then move it to another sheet, etc. before refreshing Power BI. This is the current setup and I want to simplify/automate this and yet not overload the Power BI report that it takes forever to refresh or load.

My question:  If there are calculations to be done in between the multidimensional cube data and Power BI, where should it be placed? Should I complicate the Power BI report with all these calculations or move the calculations and logic elsewhere such as for example a Python program that will connect to SSAS (I am somewhat familiar with Python). I was told to consider Databricks to run the Python code by a colleague.

**Options:**

1. Perform all calculations in Power BI. Yet to test how well the report can handle this.
2. Do the calculations elsewhere, for example on Databricks. Don't have Databricks yet. I can start with local Jupyter notebooks. I am concerned if I will run out of memory.

What is the best/industry practice in such scenarios? There are concerns about complicating the presentation layer in Power BI and impacting user experience with heavy Powe BI reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you want all logic in the cube and use Power BI for reporting. If you can't put the logic in the cube, I would prefer to do it in Power BI to eliminate other points of failure, manual steps, or timing issues.